How can you Localize Display Dates (i.e. locale formatting) with Material Date Picker in Angular? (Using Luxon)
I have a form builder with properties as follows:
startDateLocal: this.fb.nonNullable.control<DateTime>(
    {
      value: DateTime.fromISO(startDateLocal ?? defaultStartDate.toISO()),
      disabled: // business logic for disabling
    },
    Validators.required
),
endDateLocal: this.fb.nonNullable.control<DateTime>(
    DateTime.fromISO(endDateLocal ?? defaultEndDate.toISO()),
    Validators.required
)


Note that endDateLocal is just an ISO string representing the time in the time zone a program is active in.
Normally, I would do something like:
DateTime.FromISO(endDateLocal).toLocaleString(DateTime.DATE_SHORT)

and just display the locale string, but the form is linked to an actual date time object so I can't just use a string here.
Here is the relevant HTML if this helps:
          <input
            matInput
            [matDatepicker]="endDate"
            formControlName="endDateLocal"
            [min]="minEndDate$ | async"
            [matDatepickerFilter]="endDateFilter"
          />

